# Trying to add feature to vector source but getting an error in version 5.3.5

Tags: openlayers

I am following openlayers documentation and from this webpage:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#addFeature
I understand that the features option can read input as a feature object or a collection. However both ways, I am getting errors.

Here's my code:

```
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import Polygon from 'ol/geom/Polygon';
import Feature from 'ol/feature';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import collection from 'ol/collection'
import {GeoJSON} from 'ol/format';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})

export class MapComponent implements OnInit{
  Map: any;
  pointData:any;
  geometry: any;
  featureObject: any;
  center:any = transform([-97.30934, 32.7687988], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
  layers:Array<any> = [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ];
  extent:any;
  vectorSource:any;
  vectorLayer:any;
  collection:any;

constructor() {
this.pointData = [[2433903.684, 13449511.792], [2402285.854, 13472141.717], 
          [2367866.204, 13491472.411], [2335288.597, 13520605.690]];         
this.geometry = new Polygon(this.pointData);
this.geometry.extent_ = [2314445.434787005, 13449511.792723179, 2501576.4506160878, 13586799.08540526];
this.featureObject = new Feature({name:"myFile", geometry:this.geometry});
this.featureObject.setId("myFile")
this.collection = new collection(this.pointData)
 }
}
```

Now if I create VectorSource by adding featureObject I am getting this error:

```
this.vectorSource = new VectorSource({format:new GeoJSON(), features:this.featureObject});
```

I am getting this error as if vector source needs a collection as input instead:

```
ERROR TypeError: collection.getArray is not a function
    at new VectorSource (Vector.js:262)
```

If I add feature using a collection like so:

```
this.vectorSource = new VectorSource({format:new GeoJSON(), features:this.collection});
```

I get the following error as if it needs a feature input instead:

```
core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: feature.getId is not a function
    at VectorSource.addToIndex_ (Vector.js:348)
    at VectorSource.addFeaturesInternal (Vector.js:388)
    at new VectorSource (Vector.js:268)
```

when I use:

```
this.vectorSource = new VectorSource({}); 
this.vectorSource.addFeature(this.featureObject);
console.log(this.vectorSource);
```

vector source does not appear to take the feature:

```
VectorSource {disposed_: false, pendingRemovals_: {…}, dispatching_: {…}, listeners_: {…}, revision_: 1, …}
attributionsCollapsible_: true
attributions_: null
dispatching_: {}
disposed_: false
featureChangeKeys_: {36: Array(2)}
featuresCollection_: null
featuresRtree_: RBush {rbush_: rbush, items_: {…}}
format_: undefined
listeners_: {}
loadedExtentsRtree_: RBush {rbush_: rbush, items_: {…}}
loader_: ƒ VOID()
loading: false
nullGeometryFeatures_: {}
ol_uid: "38"
overlaps_: true
pendingRemovals_: {}
projection_: null
revision_: 1
state_: "ready"
strategy_: ƒ all(extent, resolution)
undefIdIndex_: {}
url_: undefined
values_:
__proto__: Object
wrapX_: true
__proto__: Source
```

Bottom line is that I am unable to create a vector source.

Comment: features should be an **array** of features `this.vectorSource = new VectorSource({format:new GeoJSON(), features:[this.featureObject]});`  or a collection of features ` this.collection = new collection([this.featureObject])`

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot. When is it appropriate to use `module:ol/Collection~Collection` or `<module:ol/Feature~Feature>` to include a feature object in vector source as shown on this page: [link](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html)

Comment: Usually an array of features is sufficient, but a features collection can be shared with another source or an interaction, and can be used to keep features in a known order, e.g. `source.getFeatures().forEach(...)`  would process features in a random order while `source.getFeaturesCollection().forEach(...)` would process them in the order they were added